# Visual / HTML tabs vanished on editor

Tags: posts, editor

The Visual / HTML tabs have vanished on the editor on posts and pages.  I'm not sure when this happened, but I've tried deactivating my plugins with no joy.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Lucy

Comment: Tried another browser? Got javascript disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Check your profile's prefs, for starters.

And if you're configured to use the wysiwyg editor, make sure no is error is being reported in the edit posts page.

Comment: @Lucy: In other words, go to your user profile and uncheck the first check-box if it is checked.

Comment: to clarify, "the first check-box" is 
`Visual Editor  (X)  Disable the visual editor when writing`

Answer (score 1):

Check also the theme, maybe use for a test the default theme. In different cases was a problem with javascript, a plugin or theme has include a error with custom scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen before and it was a result of missing js files in the wp-includes/js/ directory.  Try reinstalling to see if it fixes the problem for you.